# What is the derivative of $\frac{\sin^3x}{3}$?

Tags: derivatives

> $$\dfrac{\sin^3x}{3}$$

How do I derive this?

I got this: $\sin^2 x$, is it correct?

Comment: no, it's not correct. Use the chain rule.

Comment: That is close, you forgot the chain rule.

Comment: What's the chain rule ?

Comment: The chain rule says that $\frac{df}{dx}=\frac{df}{dg}\frac{dg}{dx}$.

Comment: I really want to help, so please let me know if I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best possible answer I can give you.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Comment: Are you getting the derivative with respect to $x$?

Answer (score 3):

By chain rule:$$(f(x)^n)'= nf(x)^{n-1}f'(x)$$ So $$\left(\frac{\sin^3(x)}{3}\right)'=\sin^2(x)\cos(x)$$

Comment: here: f(x)=sin(x) and n=3

Comment: could you explain how you got the general formula ?

Comment: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/differential-calculus/taking-derivatives/chain_rule/v/chain-rule-introduction

Comment: and you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) too. also google "chain rule derivative proof"

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{d\frac{\sin^3 x}{3}}{dx}&=\left(\frac13\right)\left( \frac{d\sin^3 x}{d\sin x}\right) \left(\frac{d\sin x}{dx}\right)\\
&=\left(\frac13\right)\left(3\sin^2 x\right)\left( \cos x\right) \\
&=\sin^2 x \cos x
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$$f(x)=\sin{x}$$
$$g(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}$$
$$g(f(x))=\frac{\sin^3(x)}{3}$$

Then:

$$[g(f(x))]'=g'(f(x))f'(x)=\sin^2(x)\cos{x}$$

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the chain rule
$$(\frac{sin^3x}{3})'=\frac{3sin^2x\cdot(sinx)'}{3}=sin^2x\cdot cosx$$

You forgot to differentiate $sinx$ itself.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\dfrac{\sin^3x}{3}$  which can be written as $f(x)=\dfrac{(\sin x)^3}{3}$.
Here chain rule says $f'(x)=n[g(x)]^{n-1}g'(x)$. So $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{3}3[sinx]^2cosx$.